# Compile all Classes not catching a compilation error?

Tags: apex

While trying to install an update to an unlocked package (with no namespace) in an org, we received an unexpected compilation failure from existing code that doesn't interact with the package code.  My assumption is that installing the package caused the system to compile all classes, or at least all non-namespaced classes.

The compilation error is pretty obvious.  A trigger failed to compile because it called a method, passing a `Set<Id>`:

```
opportunityDataStamper.opportunityStampAtInsert(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
```

But the method expects a List:

```
public static void opportunityStampAtInsert(Opportunity[] triggerOpps) {
```

I have confirmed there is no other version of that method in the class with another signature.

I had thought to demonstrate this issue to the team who owns the trigger by using the "Compile all Classes" link in Setup > Custom Code > Apex Classes, but to my astonishment, it reported that all classes had compiled successfully.  Then I opened the trigger in Developer Console, added a space to an empty line, and tried to save, and sure enough I got the error message.  Just to be sure, I tried this in another sandbox with the same result.

Is this a Salesforce bug or am I overlooking something?  Does "Compile All Classes" *only* compile managed code or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing a package compiles *all* code, and any deployment in production also compiles *all* code, but the "Compile all classes" function does *not* compile triggers. To find problems with triggers, you need to use the "Compile all triggers" function found in Setup | Apex Triggers, instead.

Comment: I am embarrassed to say that after 11+ years on the platform, I never realized there is a 'Compile all Triggers' function.  Learned something today, thanks!  Oddly, clicking the link makes it disappear, with no "compiling" spinner.  Eventually the completion status does appear.

Comment: @JasonClark The compile all triggers feature is something that you or I, people who have been in the system for ages, might have missed, because it was only introduced somewhere around 2018. I just found it today myself for the first time, too. Historically, I used to deploy all triggers with a tool to verify compilation status. Nice to have a UI option now.